# how to Open links from VB.net Web Browser in default browser

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web, browser

am using the built in Web Browser in Visual basic to display my Adsense Ads which are displayed on my webpage. This works well. The only problem is that when you have an ad clicked, it opens up inside the application.

I have had a look here: Making all Links in a Web View open in the Default Browser

and it says about WebPolicyDelegate and I am unsure about how to do this.

Is there anyway to have a clicked link open in the default internet browser rather then in vb.net (visual studio 2010)

Thanks Chris

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked the terms and service when using Adsense, they require that ads be opened in the same window.  This may have since changed, but you should read the TOS to confirm.  This functionality you are experiencing is by design.

This is highlighted here:  http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1354740